# Is there a way to work with GraphQL and Elasticsearch in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, elasticsearch, graphql

I'm working on a project in which I have our models divided into two different databases, PostgreSQL and Elasticsearch.

I'm trying to use GraphQL just for queries (I'm not planning on using mutations), and be able with the same endpoint to launch queries to PostgreSQL or Elasticsearch depending on where the model is stored.

So, depending on the model:

1. If the model is in PostgreSQL, I can use the default behaviour of GraphQL, parsing and launching the query via ActiveRecord.
2. If the model is in Elasticsearch, I need to first transform the GraphQL query into an Elasticsearch query, run that query against Elasticsearch, and transform the result back to GraphQL output format.

So, first problem here is how do I transform queries from GraphQL format to Elasticsearch format. I've been looking over internet and just found [this plugin](https://github.com/graphql-compose/graphql-compose-elasticsearch) for js and [this response](https://www.reddit.com/r/graphql/comments/5wbn6y/is_there_a_way_to_get_elasticsearch_working_with/) without no so much information in reddit.

Then, the second problem is how do I make that depending on the model, launch the query against PostgreSQL or Elasticsearch. For this I found nothing :(

And the last problem is parse the response and transform in into the expected GraphQL output. Also found nothing here, but I need to resolve these two first points before starting with this one.

I would like to know if someone has been working on this kind of structure and If he could point me to some guide or resource with which I could start working on my solution.

Comment: How do you handle the Elasticsearch in Rails app? Did you use gem like [chewy](https://github.com/toptal/chewy) or [elasticsearch-rails](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails) ?

Comment: I'm using elasticsearch-rails -> elasticsearch-persistence (i'm not adding elasticsearch-model in order to maintain the logic out of the model itself)